# Pull date from mongo _id on the client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I use my document `_id` client-side as strings. I would love to be able pull the timestamp from this value as you can on the server. Is it possible to recreate this functionality on the client side? (recast as objectid, or create a standalone function to pull this data)

example `_id: "4f94c2a11a6bbec3872cb315"`

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about this, broken down into steps... unfortunately it's only second resolution time that gets stored in the ObjectID.

```
var id = "4f94c2a11a6bbec3872cb315"​;
// first 4 bytes are the timestamp portion (8 hex chars)
var timehex = id.sub​string(0,8);
console.log(timehex); // gives: 4f94c2a1

// convert to a number... base 16
var secondsSinceEpoch = parseInt(timehex, 16);
console.log(secondsSinceEpoch); // gives: 1335149217

// convert to milliseconds, and create a new date
var dt = new Date(secondsSinceEpoch*1000);
console.log(dt);​ // gives: Sun Apr 22 2012 22:46:57 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

See jsfiddle if you want to test: http://jsfiddle.net/pZdyM/

**NOTE**: this is kind of kludgy--it depends on the current ObjectID format. They might move the timestamp around within the ObjectID one day, and that would break this.

Comment: cool, this is a pretty rad start, and I know where the time hex is located now :) -- I wonder if there's even a way to future proof this, probably just always need to know what version of things I'm running and how the hex is stored.

Comment: They were discussing moving the time to somewhere less significant than the far left bytes, so as to make ObjectID better as a sharding key. But it looks like they're going to try to do something else, like this: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2001 So it might be safer than I thought. http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/0e807bee202d18ee?pli=1